# How can I get a listing of all buffers and the frames displaying them?

Tags: buffers, window, frames

I want to get a list of all the windows and their frames, so I can jump directly to the frame and window.

If a buffer is not open in a window then the command should still jump to the last frame in which that buffer was displayed and open a window on the buffer in that frame, else it should open it in a frame designated as the default for opening existing buffers, or the current one if none has been set.

Comment: My guess is that there are a number of packages that already provide behavior similar to what it is that you seek, and you are reinventing the wheel so to speak.  Getting a list as you describe is not sufficient to locate a particular buffer that may be displayed in one or more windows of the desired frame, and then selecting just one of those windows (if such a window exists at all).  Please consider editing your question to better describe what it is that you actually want to do, and perhaps provide an example ...

Comment: So that the forum participants do not duplicate efforts already made in the reddit/emacs forums, I am providing a link to that thread by this same O.P.:  https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/jlitex/how_can_i_jump_to_a_window_in_another_frame/

Comment: @lawlist There is a distinction between what one wants to accomplish, and acquiring the necessary technical info to accomplish it if there are packages that do it or are unsatisfactory for your needs. This question is having code that provides the technical info to enable me to accomplish what I need in my own way. The reddit question is about knowing if there is an existing solution for what I want to accomplish. The different titles of the question show the difference. This question is concerned with generating the raw information itself. Moving to the frame itself is secondary

Comment: How about?  `(mapcar (lambda (frame) (cons frame (list (window-list frame)))) (frame-list))`  That will produce a list with elements consisting `(FRAME (WINDOWS ....))`

Comment: Thanks. How can this be written to print each window on a separate line grouped by frame?

Comment: @lawlist  I have seen your hidden answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/26452049. It has the ability to jump to a window, but it doesn't list all windows

Comment: @lawlist Your last comment is a valid answer, and regardless of how short it is should should make it into a proper answer. What I need is the working knowledge of elisp that I can use to create a completion dialog to move to the right window in the right frame, but technically speaking my question is answered.

Comment: emacs.stackexchange.com is setup in such a way such that there is one discrete question per thread, with a finite set of possible correct answers.  I posted a select window/frame example using `ido` to the reddit / emacs thread, even though it is not the user interface format that you are seeking -- perhaps you can dissect it and write your own function using select portions of that example.